# Как подключить шрифты в Django?

Tags: python, django

Проект делаю на Django. Структура статических файлов такова:
static/css и static/fonts.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa';
  src: local("../fonts/Comfortaa-Light.ttf"), url("../fonts/Comfortaa-Light.ttf") format("ttf");
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Шрифты подгружаю таким образом, но когда пытаюсь использовать ничего не работает и в консоли в Sources папка fonts не загружается

Answer (score 1):

При подключении формат файла следует задавать полным именем, в вашем случае: `format("truetype")`. Вариант с `ttf` отображаться не будет, во всяком случае в третьей джанге.